# Group regex with two fixed-length numbers and remove its leading zeros

Tags: python, regex

I get a 15-digits input string, i.e. `001230123456789`.
It has two numbers - the first is `00123` (min. 1 non-zero digit, max. 5 digits), the second is `0123456789` (min. `100000000`, max. 10 digits). The captured output (those numbers) should not contain leading zeros.

The easier and, probably, the only proper way to do it (in Python) is the array slicing and lstrip():

```
input = "001230123456789"
output = [(input[:5].lstrip('0'), input[5:].lstrip('0'))]
# ('123', '123456789')
```

But I have a task to do the same thing with a regular expression.

I'm stuck with having zome zeros left, whether I've tried greedy options or not.
I've ended with that one: `0{0,4}([1-9]\d{0,4})0?([1-9]\d{8,9})`
and it passes 3/6 of my tests:

```
000010111111111 -    ('10', '111111111')     (should be ('1', '111111111'))
116402151672479 - OK ('11640', '2151672479')
006421651672479 -    ('6421', '651672479')   (should be ('642', '1651672479'))
712120751672479 - OK ('71212', '751672479')
712121551672479 - OK ('71212', '1551672479')
006400351672479 -    ('6400', '351672479')   (should be ('640', '351672479'))
```

Is there any way to do it with just a regex?

Full sample source code with a test and expected values on [pastie.org](http://pastie.org/private/e0cp3fvuhg1ax2rhikxkqq).

Comment: who assigned the task?  Looks like you already have a non-regex solution, which is usually preferable and faster...so why regex?  Sounds like homework.

Comment: Can you use two regular expressions? One two separate numbers and one to remove zeros? Completing this process with just a single one is pretty much impossible, I think.

Comment: Nikola -- very possible, just ugly :p

Comment: @NikolaMalešević Sadly, I was told to do that with just a single one. With two expressions it becomes easy, perhaps it was the point.

Comment: @IOXenus - how would the 2nd part have a min of `100000000` without leading zeroes if the string has to be 15 digit. Can you give us an example?

Comment: @Kash - I think he just meant that the captured _output_ needs to be without leading zeroes.  I was confused on that too.

Comment: @acheong87 - Yup you are right. Makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go.

```
    /^0*(\d{1,5})(?<=.{5})(?<!00000)(?!00)(?=\d{10}$)0*(.+)/
      | |        |        |         |     |          | |
      | |        |        |         |     |          | capture 2nd number
      | |        |        |         |     |          |
      | |        |        |         |     |          chomp leading zeroes
      | |        |        |         |     |
      | |        |        |         |     assert there're 10 digits ahead
      | |        |        |         |
      | |        |        |         assert second part at least 100000000
      | |        |        |
      | |        |        make sure first part at least one nonzero digit
      | |        |
      | |        assert there are 5 chars behind (already tested numeric)
      | |
      | capture 1st number (don't worry; the assertions will fix this up)
      |
      chomp leading zeroes (i'm going to line up these comments damn it!)
```

Here's [a Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/xOsS1ZspJN).

(The `(?:^|\s)` and `(?:\s|$)` are for presentation purposes only.)

And here are the results:

```
    000010111111111             -->     1       111111111
    116402151672479             -->     11640   2151672479
    006421651672479             -->     642     1651672479
    712120751672479             -->     71212   751672479
    712121551672479             -->     71212   1551672479
    006400351672479             -->     640     351672479

    # not enough digits        
    71212155167247              -->     no match

    # too many digits          
    7121215516724798            -->     no match           

    # first part == 0          
    000001551672479             -->     no match            

    # second part < 100,000,000
    712120098765479             -->     no match
```

Comment: Note: It may seem like I have ordered atoms in weird ways, and if you can find a more "sensible" ordering, by all means, please try it and let me know. But with this many lookaround assertions, both positive and negative, I found that the expression was extremely order-sensitive. All the placements are quite deliberate.

Comment: You would need your `(?:^|\s)` to give a no match for exceeding digits. +1 for the way you handled leading zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not super familiar with python, but the below solution (perl) will do exactly what you want; though it is ugly.

```
use strict;

my @test = qw/000010111111111 116402151672479 006421651672479 712120751672479 712121551672479 006400351672479/;

foreach(@test){
    /^(?|([1-9]\d{4})|0([1-9]\d{3})|00([1-9]\d{2})|000([1-9]\d)|0000([1-9]))(?|0([1-9]\d{8})|([1-9]\d{9}))/;
    print "$_: ($1, $2)\n";
}

exit 0;
```

Taking a quick look at the python re page, I don't see `(?|...)` explicitly, but it does have `(?:...)`.  In that case you would get an array of matches, which would only have two non-blank entries -- which would be your answer.

Comment: Haha, that was my last resort! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure of another way to do it, since you really need conditional logic based on match length of leading zeroes.

Comment: @LoneShepherd Ugly indeed! I was thinking about your way of doing it, but than said to myself it cannot be possible that someone wants OP to write regex with 5 different cases for the first number and 10 for the second. It turns out I've missed that the second one has a minimum, rendering just two cases for it. Great job! +1

Comment: @LoneShepherd - You can emulate the "conditional" logic by relying on the fact that there's a maximum string length, i.e. forcing backtracking by asserting length in the right places :D - see my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Python regex:

```
0{0,4}(\d+)(?<=^\d{5})0{0,9}(\d+)
|     |    |          |     |
|     |    |          |     Second number without leading zeros
|     |    |          Up to 9 leading zeros of second number
|     |    Must be preceded by start of string and 5 digits
|     First number without leading zeros
Up to 4 leading zeros of first number
```

Comment: Looks great, thanks! Though the second part should be `0?(\d{9,10})` since I do have a minimal second number value - it has at least 9 digits (and the first one is not a zero)

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution:

```
re.search(r'([1-9]\d*)(?=\d{10})0*([1-9]\d*)', "0064000351672479").groups()
# ('640', '351672479')
```

Breakdown:

- `([1-9]\d*)` - first group, must start whith 1-9,
- `(?=\d{10})` - look ahead assertion that we have 10 digital,
- `0*`         - chomp leaders zeroes from second number,
- `([1-9]\d*)` - the second group (number).